# Working with a web extension native-messaging API in multiple tab scenario

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to understand how to properly handle a multiple-tab scenario for web extension that, through the native-messaging API, utilizes a locally stored application through a runtime communication port.

I have one set up and working; but I don't understand what is supposed to take place when more than one browser tab uses the native application.  I was planning on opening the native application only once to handle requests from all tabs that can use it, but am uncertain now. I should probably state that the application remains open and listening for new requests rather than closing after each individual request. It's opened by the background script which handles the requests from each tab's content script.

What happens if a request to the native application from one tab is still processing and a user switches to another tab and sends an additional request to the same native application?  Will both requests process, is the second blocked, or will the first cease mid way and the second begin?

I can alter the set up to open a separate instance of the native application for each tab. At least I can see multiple processes open in the task manager rather than one only, when I do this.

Even in the scenario of one instance of the native application per browser tab, what happens if the user clicks the button twice, so to speak, before the first request completes? Should there always be a native_app_busy check that ignores the second request if the first is still processing?

I have a lot of experimenting to do, of course, but thought it prudent to ask how it is supposed to work. Thank you.

Comment: If the host process is busy it can't receive anything so the message is queued. When the process reads it, the callback in the extension will fire. So there should be no problems with the transport, but adding that busy flag seems like a good idea anyway. As for whether you should go multi-process, it depends on what the host app does. In some cases it's a good solution, while in other cases it may be better to use threads inside one process.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for the explanation. I'm going to try the single process first.